# Get the element under a touchend

Tags: javascript, touch-event

As the `touchend` event is bind to the element where the `touchstart` is fired, how can I get the element at the position where the finger leaves, when this is outside of the element where the event was binded to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use the `document.elementFromPoint` method, passing it the coordinates of the event:

```
$('#element').on("touchend",function(event){
    var endTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
        event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
        event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY
    );
});
```

**EDIT:**
Found some good article about getting elements at specific coordinates.
http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/

Comment: It seems to work, but I have to use `event.changedTouches[0].pageX` to get the coordinates. Is cause of testing in chrome with emulated touch events?

Comment: This fails for an element that is `position:fixed` and has (statically positioned) elements underneath.

Comment: I need this on multitouch - would like to know which if the touches[] has ended

Comment: On mobile Safari, `originalEvent.touches` seems to be an empty list on `touchend`. Only on `touchstart` does it contain a `Touch` object.