# How to determine element touched on touchend for a page with layers

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I cannot supply a follow up question as of yet to [Get the element under a touchend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596121/get-the-element-under-a-touchend) , so I am opening a new issue.  I want to get the element under a touchend that is different from the touchstart, but my page has absolutely positioned elements, and the function `document.elementFromPoint` keeps on returning my background element instead of every element in front of it.  How do I get the *actual* element being touched?

Comment: What does `e.target` point to?

Comment: `e.target` points to an anchor tag with id "play".  `document.elementFromPoint` then points to a div of id "background", even if my `ontouchend` also occurs on "play".