# touchstart on one element, drag, touchend on another element

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I have a color picker that should allow to pick two different colours at once; it should work like this.
touch the first color -> drag to the second color -> release finger on second color.
The problem is that right now when I lift the finger from the screen the touchend event fires on the first color. It works fine with clicks, though.

```js
$('.single-color').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
  $('#color1').val(index);
  $('#color1').attr('data-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
  console.log('touchstart - index: ' + $(this).attr('data-index'));
});

$('.single-color').on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
  $('#color2').val(index);
  $('#color2').attr('data-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
  console.log('touchend - index: ' + $(this).attr('data-index'));
});
```

```css
.colors {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.single-color {
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="colors">
      
  <li class="single-color" data-color="#4DB023" data-index="0" style="background-color: #4DB023">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#1E6B3D" data-index="1" style="background-color: #1E6B3D">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#233778" data-index="2" style="background-color: #233778">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#3098FF" data-index="3" style="background-color: #3098FF">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#FF0000" data-index="4" style="background-color: #FF0000">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#38889C" data-index="5" style="background-color: #38889C">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#483063" data-index="6" style="background-color: #483063">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

</ul>
```

To replicate the problem look at the above snippet, setting the viewport to iPhone6 in the Chrome Resposive tool so it simulates touches.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using this answer: [Get the element under a touchend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596121/get-the-element-under-a-touchend)

```js
var $singleColors = $('.single-color');
$singleColors.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
  $singleColors.removeClass('active1');
  $(this).addClass('active1');
  $('#color1').val(index);
  $('#color1').attr('data-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
  console.log('touchstart - index: ' + $(this).attr('data-index'));
});

$singleColors.on('mouseup touchmove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var endTarget = document.elementFromPoint(
    e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
    e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY
  );
  var index = $(endTarget).attr('data-index');
  $singleColors.removeClass('active2');
  $(endTarget).addClass('active2');
  $('#color2').val(index);
  $('#color2').attr('data-color', $(endTarget).css('background-color'));
  console.log('touchend - index: ' + $(endTarget).attr('data-index'));
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.colors {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.single-color {
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}

.single-color.active1, .single-color.active2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="colors active2">
      
  <li class="single-color active1" data-color="#4DB023" data-index="0" style="background-color: #4DB023">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#1E6B3D" data-index="1" style="background-color: #1E6B3D">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#233778" data-index="2" style="background-color: #233778">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#3098FF" data-index="3" style="background-color: #3098FF">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#FF0000" data-index="4" style="background-color: #FF0000">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color active1 active2" data-color="#38889C" data-index="5" style="background-color: #38889C">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

  <li class="single-color" data-color="#483063" data-index="6" style="background-color: #483063">
    &nbsp;
  </li>

</ul>
```

Note: This script doesn't work anymore on desktop. It only works on touch devices.